# How to store sub-query result in session variable using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

I am trying to store sub-query result in session variable using MySQL, but the issue is when I execute this Query like this (see the Query below) the error message will be show like this (see the Error message below).

I don't know how to solve this issue.

```
(0 row(s) affected)
Execution Time : 00:00:00:343
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:343

Error Code : 1222
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
```

Query

```
SET @post := 0;

SELECT user_name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @post  FROM post WHERE user_id = '23332'),
@post 
FROM `user_fans` WHERE user_id = '23332';
```

Comment: Why are you using session variables for this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @post := 0;

SELECT  user_name,
        @post := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post WHERE user_id = '23332'),
        @post 
FROM    `user_fans`
WHERE   user_id = '23332';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want use  the post count further then it is fine

If you want to just display the post count then use

```
SELECT  user_name,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post WHERE user_id = '23332') as Post,
FROM    `user_fans`
WHERE   user_id = '23332';
```